# How to use arcade module on Raspberry-pi TFT /dev/fb1?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, arcade

I want to create a simple watch with python `arcade` library that will be displayed on a TFT screen from raspberry pi.

I don't know how to get the arcade image data and send it to the `/dev/fb1` (framebuffer).

In `pygame` it is possible with something like this:

```py
import pygame

surfaceSize = (320, 240)
pygame.init()
lcd = pygame.Surface(surfaceSize)
f = open("/dev/fb1","wb")
f.write(lcd.convert(16,0).get_buffer())
f.close()
```

Code from [raspberrypi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=234087)

Comment: arcade is [based on OpenGL and Pyglet](https://arcade.academy/pygame_comparison.html) so you may have to search in [Pyglet documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/gl.html) if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Arcade's own comparison with Pygame](https://arcade.academy/pygame_comparison.html), this is not possible:

> Features that Pygame has that the Arcade Library does not:
>    ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ *[...]*
>    ⚫ Does not require OpenGL, so works on Raspberry Pis